# Printing the number of files in a directory hourly in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose in a directory there are N number of files, we need to display/log the number of files present after every one hour.

ex: No of files at 10:00 AM :25
    No of files at 11:00 AM :22

so we need to create a timed action, I thought of using Thread.sleep(XXX) to suspend the Thread for 1 hour and then again get the count and print.
please suggest better alternatives.

Comment: Try [quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: use cronJob for scheduling. https://linuxize.com/post/scheduling-cron-jobs-with-crontab/

Comment: You can use a **TaskScheduler** to acquire the file count at a specific schedule or you could use the **WatchService** class to constantly maintain a dynamic count within the directory **as soon as** a change happens (a file is added or deleted).

Answer (score 0):

Use `TimerTask` - A task that can be scheduled for one-time or repeated execution by a Timer.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimeIt {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Task performed on " + new Date());
                // Complete lo
                final int count = new File("/tmp/").list().length;
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        };
        final Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000L, 1000L);

        Thread.sleep(1000L * 2);
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

[TimerTask Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

[Java Timer and TimerTask](https://www.baeldung.com/java-timer-and-timertask)